# How to split string in script

Tags: javascript, function, explode

in this function

```
$(document).on("click",".change",function(){
    var id = this.id;

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url('discussions/reader/change_flag')?>",
        type: "post",

        //dataType:"Json",
        data: {
            "id": id
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);

        }

    });

});
```

id is "r_1" and I want to split this into "r" and "1" and use these separately. I used explode but it didn't work what can I do?

Comment: *"I used explode but..."* Well, `explode` is a PHP function, but this is JavaScript. Did you try any *JavaScript* functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use like this:

```
var id = this.id;//"r_1"
var rr = id.split('_');
//and use like this:
rr[0];//"r"
rr[1];//"1"
```

Answer (score 0):

`explode` is a PHP function hence it wont work in javascript.

use `split('_')`